# Going from a string to a type of protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Im looking to do something a little strange.
Is there a way to go from String to a protocol in swift like

```
let protocolString: String = "customProtocol"
```

I have an avalible protocol like:

```
public protocol customProtocol{}
```

now later on I know the string name of the protocol but not the actual protocol so I want to do something like:

```
   if let conformantObject = randomeObject as? protocolFromString(protocolString) {
    //hey it conformed to the protocol    
   }
```

is there anyhting that does this conversion?

Comment: What would you expect `conformantObject` to be statically typed as, given that the value of `protocolString` isn't known until runtime? It would have to be `Any`, so you wouldn't be able to call anything on it – which I imagine would defeat the purpose of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: No it's not possible with that approach. Once the code is compiled, there is no longer any String representation of the protocol (i.e. the computer doesn't store the name of your protocol in any human readable form). Could you share some more information on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @toddg Actually, the Swift compiler does include this type metadata, but it's not user accessible (there's no user reflection APIs that let you get at it). Xcode and other related tools use it, however. In any case, you wouldn't be able to cast to an unknown protocol, because it wouldn't be of any use to the static type system.